# Setting a Max Height for Added Images

Tags: html, css, image, dreamweaver

I am making an artist website and want to add a few photos of my work. I want the images to be responsive to the page, which I can do by making max-width 100%, however the image grows too long in height and requires the viewer to scroll to see the entire image. See attached images, one where the image fits on the screen and one where extending the page has made it not fit.

[Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBqYT.png)

[Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cds4I.png)

How do I set the image to not grow beyond the height of the current window? I have tried working with max-height, to no avail. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Best,
Weston Uram

Comment: It would be easier to suggest if you include your code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<head>
 <!-- add viewport meta to the head -->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

css:

```
img {
   display:block;
   margin:auto;
   max-width:80vw;
   max-height:80vh;
}
```